# Microsoft Graph API V2 application add static permissions failure

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am having problem migrating to Microsoft graph V2 applications, from V1 Applications.

As part of the backward compatibility offered by the new V2 applications, I can see the applications form the original V1 applications portals (old and new), however I cannot modify the application due to unknown errors (see attached screen shots).

The reason I want to use the original portal is to add permissions to other applications (In the documentation of V2 its called 'static permissions') such as 'Office365 management activity API', I think it is possible using '/applications' resource but I didn't find in the documentation how to do it.

Does someone encountered such problem and know how to overcome it or used the Graph API to get permissions for other Microsoft REST APIs?

[image: app id]

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For v1 apps, you should use the "App Registrations" blade in the newer [Azure Portal (portal.azure.com)](https://portal.azure.com).** This blade has a "Required Permissions" section where you can add different permissions for different APIs.

**For v2 apps, you should use the [Application Registration Portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com)](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).** This portal has a "Microsoft Graph Permissions" section where you can add different permissions for the Microsoft Graph.

**At this time, v2 apps only support permissions to the Microsoft Graph**, if you want to access other APIs (like the Office 365 Management  Activity API) you'll need to use v1 apps.

You should not use the classic Azure portal (manage.windowsazure.com) for anything really at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I need V2 application because I want to use /applications resource to update the key-credentials (certificate) and afterwards get AppToken using the same certificate and access the office 365 management API. I already able to see the V2 application using the V1 portal but as I wrote due to unknown error I cannot save changes in the app

Comment: /applications shows both v1 and v2 apps. However you can only modify v1 apps as v2 apps are currently read only. So the recommendation still stands, you should use a v1 app.

Comment: I cannot use /applications with 'patch' HTTP method, I receive the following response: `{error={code=Request_BadRequest, message=Updates to V1 applications is not supported through this api version., innerError={...}}..}`

Comment: You should use the Azure AD Graph's /applications

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference

Comment: I did use /applications, the following response was for the following HTTP call: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<id>` with modified key credentials: `Updates to V1 applications is not supported through this api version.`

Comment: That's from the Microsoft Graph. See the link I shared for the Azure AD Graph. Yiu should be issuing requests to https://graph.windows.net/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/applications/?api-version=1.6

Comment: Note that'll you'll need different permissions in the portal, these are "Windoss Azure Active Directory"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146986/discussion-between-asafm-and-saca).

Comment: Using  V1.6 API you offered worked (`https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#CommonQueries`), do you recommend using is it production ready?

Comment: The Azure AD Graph (graph.windows.net, v1.6) is definitely production ready, it's been for years now. Eventually it'll be replaced by the Microsoft Graph (graph.microsoft.com, v1.0) but it still has ways to go.

Comment: Can you please flag this question as answered if you are good to go?